# Error when trying to install pyDNS for python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

When I try to install pyDNS by "**pip install pyDNS**" i get;

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\עידן\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\עידן\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-856byly1\\pydns\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\עידן\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-856byly1\\pydns\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: C:\Users\עידן\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-856byly1\pydns\
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\עידן\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-856byly1\pydns\setup.py", line 12, in <module>
    import DNS
  File "C:\Users\עידן\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-856byly1\pydns\DNS\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import Type,Opcode,Status,Class
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Type'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check 
the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see `python38-32` in the directory path. It's not Python 2.7, and the module is Python2-only.